# Double customer entry in braintree vault issue

Tags: php, braintree

After completing transaction, there are two customer entry under vault.

Step I have followed:

```
1. Created customer.
//first customer vault entry is created at this point 
$customerParams = Braintree_Customer::create(array(
                    'firstName' => $firstName,
                    'lastName' => $lastName,
                  ));
```

2.Then generated clientToken

```
Braintree_ClientToken::generate(array(
   "customerId" => $customerParams->customer->id
));
```

3.Then with help of api generated nonce in js successfully:

```
var client = new braintree.api.Client({clientToken: ctoken});
client.tokenizeCard({
...
...
});
```

4.Again at this point new customer is created

```
Braintree_Transaction::sale(array(
 'amount' => $mapCidInvoiceID['amount'],
 'orderId' =>  $redirectParams['invoiceID'],
 'paymentMethodNonce' => $nonce,
 'options' => array(
    'storeInVaultOnSuccess' => true,
 ),
));
```

is there something wrong in my code? why for one transaction two customer record are created? For first record first and last name are recorded. But second case no such detail are stored.
First creation of customer is required for second and third step.

Comment: Another solution is ignore customer creation in first step and generate client token without passing any customer id. At transaction sale call, pass all customer information along with other information.

Answer (score 2):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree.</sub>

Your code is creating two separate customers because when you call Transaction::sale it does not have the customer from your Customer::create call tied to it, and you have the option set to store the payment method in the vault upon success. This creates a customer when saving the payment method from the transaction, because a payment method must be tied to a customer. To resolve your problem, pass the customer id returned from Customer::create as a customerId param when you call Transaction::sale.

```
Braintree_Transaction::sale(array(
  'amount' => $mapCidInvoiceID['amount'],
  'orderId' =>  $redirectParams['invoiceID'],
  'customerId' => $customerParams->customer->id
  'paymentMethodNonce' => $nonce,
  'options' => array(
    'storeInVaultOnSuccess' => true,
  ),
));
```